# Backbone Router and Views

Tags: backbone.js

I've been getting started with Backbone.js and trying to get my head around Routing to specific Views. In my `HTML` I have `<a href="#project/1">` tags to render the View for the tasks of a project.

**Query**

When the link is clicked, it appends the task with the `id` to the `DOM`, however, when a second link is clicked, it appends that task underneath the previous. I'm not sure if its best practice to `$.empty` the View then call the `show` method?

A snippet of my Router:

```
routes: {
    'project/:id: 'showtasks'
},

showtasks: function(id) {
   Event.trigger('tasks:show', id);
}
```

Snippet of the Collection of Tasks

```
initialize: function() {
    Event.on('tasks:show', this.show, this);
},

show: function() {
    var task = this.collection.get(id);
    var taskView = new App.Views.Task({ model: task });
    this.$el.append(taskView.render().el);
}
```

The collection

```
var tasks = new App.Collections.Tasks([
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'First Task',
        content: 'Lots of Content...'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Second Task',
        content: 'Lots of Content...'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: 'Third Task',
        content: 'Lots of Content...'
    }
]);

var tasksView = new App.Views.Tasks({ collection: tasks });
```

Comment: What do you want it to do (to only show one at a time)? Calling `$.empty` would be fine when the event is triggered. You said it's your `Collection` code, but it looks like it's really a Backbone `View` (as `Collection`s don't have an element (`$el`) associated). The code looks to be a `TaskViewViewer`? I don't know where the `id` is coming from in the `show` function... maybe just not shown?

Comment: Sorry, yes that is my 'Collection Views'. I will update my question with the collection. Eventually, I want to nest the collection, so multiple items are associated with one project

Comment: You could do empty which should clean up any events attached to the html within it or you can just call this.$el.html(taskView.render().el) instead which will replace the currently content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of good design patterns for Backbone view is:

- Calling `render` method multiple times should not have any side effect. It should render correctly.
- When you use `append` in a render, you are basically setting up the flow of your view in the render method which should be basically the responsibility of the template of your view.

So I would suggest you should use this >

```
this.$el.html(taskView.render().el);
```

This would work perfectly fine however you would get into an issue if you have subviews. For that [read this - (basically this whole answer is a shameless ripoff of this article :P )](http://ianstormtaylor.com/rendering-views-in-backbonejs-isnt-always-simple/)

Comment: +1 for a link to the article, thank you. I thought emptying and appending the DOM every time would have some overhead to it.